# Quartz.net 3.4 - starting job in global.asax doesn't fire

Tags: c#, async-await, quartz.net

I'm trying to run a simple job with quartz.net with the latest version (3.4), however it's not firing.

**Global.asax**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Quartz.Api.ScheduledTasks;

namespace Quartz.Api
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            Task.Run(async () => { await JobScheduler.Start(); });
        }
    }
}
```

**Job Scheduler**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Quartz.Impl;

namespace Quartz.Api.ScheduledTasks
{
    public class JobScheduler
    {
        public static async Task Start()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            await scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TestJob>().Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                (s =>
                    s.WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .OnEveryDay()
                        .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
                )
                .Build();

            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test job**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Quartz.Api.ScheduledTasks
{
    public class TestJob : IJob
    {
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
                 System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\GOWDY_N\source\repos\Quartz\Quartz.Api\ScheduledTasks.txt",
                     lines);
             });

        }
    }
}
```

The text file in my job code never gets written to the disk.

I suspect that I'm not using the tasks correctly because Application_Start() in my global.asax is a void method but I'm using async/await pattern in the call stack.

Does anyone know a good way to setup my job in the global.asax in quartz 3.0 or above?

Comment: I've just realized I've been looking in the wrong folder, for the text file :(. My code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        ScheduledTasks.JobScheduler.Start();
        ...
    }
}
```

Instead of writing in `Global.asax` write it in `Startup.cs` File.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no good reason to use `Task.Run` and just want to return a task, use this code instead:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Quartz.Api.ScheduledTasks
{
    public class TestJob : IJob
    {
        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(
                @"C:\Users\GOWDY_N\source\repos\Quartz\Quartz.Api\ScheduledTasks.txt",
                lines);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```